# Maria Performance Tuning: HyperThreading is great for marketing, lousy for performance

Tags: mariadb, performance-tuning, hyperthreading

I'm looking into optimizing my database server and this is what I read in Maria's official documentation [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-memory-allocation/).

How true is this? More so, how is this true?

Apologies if this is not the best place to ask this question. Please redirect me.

Comment: I think if you want an answer your going to need to ask a specific question.  The problem here is that you have an external link to extensive documentation that you expect someone to read and your question about that large body of documentation is, How is this true?  You need to ask a specific question about specific concepts.  This question is just way to broad and very unclear.  Can you put the concept you have issue with in the form of a question?

Comment: Edit your question to add what exactly you are asking to the body, and more details about your problem, your environment, and what you have tried. The title is merely an introduction, a good question cannot possibly fit in just a few words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, MySQL/MariaDB do not need much CPU.  Hence HyperThreading (etc) are not very important in the performance question.  Usually, heavy CPU usage is readily cured by

- Improving the indexes -- often via a suitable "composite" index, and/or
- Reformulating the slowest queries.

See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog for setting up the slowlog and providing suitable info for us to help you with fixing slow queries.

Hyperthreading, in hyper-simplified terms, is a compromise between number of CPU "cores" and speed of the cores.  By adding hyperthreading, designers let you simultaneously run more processes that are CPU-bound, but each one takes a little longer to finish.  A single connection to MariaDB will use only a single cpu hyperthread, so having more of them rarely helps.  And, unless you are doing especially complex queries, each query will finish "fast enough".

Which is your situation?

- Considering which server to buy?  Don't worry about CPU specs.
- You have a MariaDB installation that is having performance troubles?  Let's see the worst couple of queries to help you fix them.